# Kendo UI Grid MVC - Save event not always being called

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC grid where I have a Save event defined as follows:

```
.Events(events => events.Change("gridRowChange").Edit("onEdit").Save("onSave"))
```

In my JavaScript code I have an onSave(e) function defined that never gets called when a grid item is saved programmatically as follows:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").saveRow();
```

However, if a row is not saved programmatically, or, in other words, when the grid itself saves the row, my Save event does get called.

Comment: Here is a [small JS example](http://dojo.telerik.com/orIS) which has a custom `saveRow` event (I know your scenario slightly different with mvc but may be of some help). Maybe you don't need the parameter on your `saveRow` function?

Comment: What's happening on the grid when you trigger the saveRow() programmatically?  Looking at the saveRow source code, the "save" event will only be triggered if the grid currently has an active editContainer(cell, row, or window depending on edit mode), i.e. if the grid is not currently showing an editor, then saveRow does not trigger the save event.